# CodeIgniter 404 Page Not Found, but why?

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, http-status-code-404

I am using CodeIgniter for two applications (a public and an admin app).
The important elements of the document structure are:

```
/admin
/admin/.htaccess
/admin/index.html
/application
/application/admin
/application/public
/system
.htaccess
index.php
```

The /admin/.htaccess file looks like this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

The /admin/index.php has the following changes:

```
$system_folder = "../system";
$application_folder = "../application/admin"; (this line exists of course twice)
```

And the /application/admin/config/routes.php contains the following:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "welcome";
$route['admin'] = 'welcome';
```

Welcome is my default controller.

When I call up the Domain/admin I get a 404 Page Not Found error. When I call up the Domain/admin/welcome everything works fine. In the debug logs I get the following error message:

```
DEBUG - 2010-09-20 16:27:34 --> Config Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2010-09-20 16:27:34 --> Hooks Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2010-09-20 16:27:34 --> URI Class Initialized
ERROR - 2010-09-20 16:27:34 --> 404 Page Not Found --> admin
```

Weirdly enough this setup works perfectly on my local MAMP installation (with the localdomain/admin/), but when I publish and test it on the "live" server, I just get 404 errors.

Any ideas? What am I doing wrong?
Thanks
C.

Comment: Just a thought, is perhaps the live server not running mod_rewrite? The live server gives you only 404s or occasional ones?

Comment: It seems to be working - I just tested it with a catch all non-www-domains and redirect to google.com.  The 404 errors are definitely being generated by CI (because they use the CSS).

Comment: Just wanted to post that if you're running a NEW INSTALLATION of Codeigniter 3 and you have a space in the hosting folder's name, it will serve a 404. Version 3.0.0

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The cause of the problem was that the server was running PHP using FastCGI.

After changing the config.php to

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI";
```

everything worked.

Comment: The routing started working, but now the CLI returns `Welcome to CodeIgniter` screen. anyway around it? I've posted more information [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25545696/codeigniter-htaccess-rewriterule-result-in-404-page-not-found#comment39888065_25545696)

Answer (score 14):

You could try one of two things or a combination of both.

1. Be sure that your controller's name starts with a capital letter. eg "Mycontroller.php"
2. If you have not made any changes to your route, for some strange reason, you might have to include capital letters in your url. e.g if your controller is 'Mycontroller.php' with a function named 'testfunc' inside it, then your url will look like this: "http://www.yourdomain/index.php/Mycontroller/testfunc". Note the capital letter. (I'm assuming you haven't added the htaccess file to remove the 'index.php' part. If you have, just remove it from the url.)

I hope this helps someone

Comment: Controller indeed needs to be capitalized but accessing it through the URL does not necessarily require you to put the capital letter in the URL.

Answer (score 11):

Leaving this answer here for others who ran into my situation.

My codeigniter app was working fine in localhost/WAMP, but was unable to route and produced 404 not found errors when pushing to an AWS EC2 instance. My issue was solved from the answer from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19408349/htaccess-works-in-localhost-but-doesnt-work-in-ec2-instance) [htaccess works in localhost but doesn't work in EC2 instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19408349/htaccess-works-in-localhost-but-doesnt-work-in-ec2-instance)

(route to my admin page)
{domain}/admin was producing 404

the `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` file needs to be modified.

-after every instance of "DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"" (2 places) "AllowOverride None" needed to be changed to "AllowOverride All".

Restarted the EC2 instance from the AWS dashboard.

{domain}/admin is now accessible and working as intended.

hope this helps someone else like it helped me!

Answer (score 7):

1. Change your controller name first letter to uppercase.
2. Change your url same as your controller name.

e.g:

Your controller name is YourController

Your url must be:

http://example.com/index.php/YourController/method

Not be:

http://example.com/index.php/yourcontroller/method

Answer (score 3):

If you installed new Codeigniter, please check if you added .htaccess file on root directory.
If you didn't add it yet, please add it.
You can put default content it the .htaccess file like below.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#When your application folder isn't in the system folder
#This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
#Submitted by: Fabdrol
#Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
# If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
# can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
# Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2):

we have to give the controller name in lower cases in server side

```
$this->class = strtolower(__CLASS__);
```

Answer (score 2):

Modify apache config file as mentioned below :

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Goto line no 172 and change

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

to

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and then finally

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Answer (score 1):

Your folder/file structure seems a little odd to me. I can't quite figure out how you've got this laid out.

> Hello I am using CodeIgniter for two applications (a public and an admin app).

This sounds to me like you've got two separate CI installations. If this is the case, I'd recommend against it. Why not just handle all admin stuff in an admin controller? If you do want two separate CI installations, make sure they are definitely distinct entities and that the two aren't conflicting with one another. This line:

```
$system_folder = "../system";
$application_folder = "../application/admin"; (this line exists of course twice)
```

And the place you said this exists (/admin/index.php...or did you mean /admin/application/config?) has me scratching my head. You have admin/application/admin and a system folder at the top level?

Comment: That's actually how I structure my applications. I have an admin app and a web app. They both share a system folder ('../system'), and each have a separate app folder ('../application/admin'), ('../application/website').

Comment: It is based on this: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/managing_apps.html There is only one system folder. I moved the application folder to the same level as the system folder.

Comment: I meant that in the /admin/index.php file I have changed lines 26, 43 and 101

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was using it on `localhost` and forgot to change `RewriteBase` in `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue after migrating to a new environment and it was simply that the server didn't run mod_rewrite

a quick `sudo a2enmod rewrite`
then `sudo systemctl restart apache2`

and problem solved...

Thanks @fanis who pointed that out in his comment on the question.

Answer (score 0):

If your application is in sub-folder then the Folder name in directory and URL must be same **(case-sensitive)**.

Answer (score 0):

It happens cause of multiple reasons but the answer missing above there's the "className" while extending your controller.

Make sure your class name is the same as your controller name is your controllers. e.g.,
If your controller name is Settings.php, you must extend the controller like.

```
class Settings extends CI_Controller
{
// some actions like...
     public function __construct(){
     // and so and so...
     }
}
```